# How to increase speed TextView.setText() for SpannableStringBuilder?

Tags: android, performance, textview, settext

I have 4 buttons to show 4 text via 1 TextView. And one of 4 strings for that content has pretty long spannable string with color filter. At first, I made building string at onClick event, but it was too slow for building long spannable string. So I fixed it to build the string in onCreate method and building time was not a problem. When TextView.setText() method is called, I gave parameter by spannable string. Though moving that build time, it had bad performance too.

Is there any way to fix that bad performance?
There are no other problems, but performance.

After building the string, I just call setText method at onClick event.

```
myTextView.setText( ssb ); // ssb is SpannableStringBuilder field
                           // ssb has long String(over 4000 characters with spanned,
                           // span used ForegroundColorSpan and RelativeSizeSpan)
```

Comment: @aneal I'll find about that, thanks.

Comment: @aneal hm.. AsyncTask will not affect to this performance issue.. Building string is not a performance problem, I want to increase the speed of setText method, or find out the alterative way instead heavy spannable string that has many characters. Again, above ssb making time is not a problem.

Comment: It also depends on what device you are  running. Based on the hardware the speed varies. You can't do increase the speed at which setText gets executed. Only way is to show a progress dialog using async task until settext gets executed.

Comment: @AndroSelva On my.. just setting text has bad performance makes me gloomy.. Ah, android! Thank you for ur comment.

Comment: SpannableStringBuilder makes work a bit slower than simple String

Comment: Look likes it is pretty late to write but might someone read it. I was also searching why textview is so slow when inculudes  lengthy  spannable text. I came up with  [written blog about it](https://www.wattpad.com/245272242-adventures-in-androidland-slow-textview-is-slow) As their suggestion, you might  use multiple textview instead of one  or use there github repo if your spannable data does not need to be changed on runtime.

Comment: @MuhammedYalçınKuru Wow! You can ask this question and fetch this link in this answer, because seems it's exactly what we need, but somebody doesn't read comments, only answers.

Comment: @Acuna haha at least, the writer read. upvoted.

Comment: @Gioskhan ahaha, okay) So have you solved your problem? Because SpannableStringBuilder still extremely slow even it's custom(

Comment: @Acuna You know that plenty of times passed out. If I implement it again, I would use scrollable component like scrollview or recyclerview. Or, how about multiple textviews? For ex, each textview can have only 2 lines, and at the third line, append dynamic textview. To do this, you should divide string by lines from original string.

Comment: Sorry for forget to answer you. Unfortunately I need to to display very long text (200k+ strings). But if it's intersting for you for future - I found the solution. My problem was not in `SpannableStringBuilder`, but in `setSpan ()` method, for unknown reasons for me it working extremely slow if text processed in it by line, it working amazingly fast when you put the whole text (for example by using `Html.fromHtml` method) to it. Absolutely strange behaviour.